# Multiline text handler in flex,

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i've been working on texthandler in flex.

the refernce site i m using is `http://www.spreadshirt.net/create-your-own-t-shirt-C59`

does n e body have worked on multiline text handlers , then plzz give me some guidance, or if u have some code, on which u have worked,

thank you in advance

Comment: This question isn't at all clear. Even after reading your comments below, I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Please edit the question and clearly explain the problem and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "texthandler".

If you wanted to do something like what is in the site you linked to, you can just use a bunch of [TextInputs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextInput.html) which are bound to non-editable textInputs.

Are you using the [Text](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Text.html) component?  IT supports multiline text.  [TextArea](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextArea.html) is a component for editing text.

If you are using Flex 4, check out the [Text Layout Framework](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/).

Comment: i m sorry not making it in a clear way, actually we develop tool in websites, using flex, 

text handler is, in the T-shirt area, when u type the text in the textinputs on the right , you'll see some text in one compoenent in the t-shirt,

when u'll fill the textinputs with the text, you'll see the text on the t-shirt with the handler around it, with which u can rotate, scale or even delete that text stuff..

thats what is texthandler, 

i m still working in flex3, as ma company is still operating

Comment: So, then use TextInputs for the input; and a textArea for the "Shirt text".  You can rotate the shirt text in the third dimension using a tool such as PaperVisionD or Away3D.

Comment: k, bt textarea cant be used here, coz seperate scaling and rotations r applied on each text on the tshirt.
u can even scale the tshirt box, fontsize of all the text will be increased

ne ways thanx for such suppr

Comment: Based on the app you linked too; each line of text on the shirt does not have separate scaling and rotation properties!  However, you can keep the font size different.  Just use a bunch of one line Text components wrapped up a single component and bind their values to the TextInput somehow. Apply rotation to the composite "Component" and font size to the individual Inputs.